# Mount host directory to docker/podman container with correct permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, podman

Using:

- podman version 4.2.0
- AlmaLinux 8.7

I've created an image based on `redhat/ubi8` with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/redhat/ubi8
RUN dnf install -y gcc-c++ cmake python39 openssh git
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash foobar -g users
USER foobar
WORKDIR /home/foobar/
RUN mkdir -p .ssh

$ docker build -t mount_test_image .
```

I run the image from a directory that contains a directory `ssh`, and I want to mount that directory to `/home/foobar/.ssh` with ownership of `foobar.users`

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 host_user users   269 Dec  7 09:10 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x. 2 host_user users    18 Dec  2 10:41 ssh


docker run -it -d --rm --mount type=bind,src=ssh,target=/home/foobar/.ssh --name=mount_test mount_test_image
```

However when I enter the container via

```
docker exec -it mount_test '/bin/sh'
```

The home directory looks like this:

```
drwx------. 1 foobar  users  18 Dec  7 17:10 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root    root   21 Dec  7 17:10 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 foobar  users  18 Jun 20 11:31 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. 1 foobar  users 141 Jun 20 11:31 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--. 1 foobar  users 376 Jun 20 11:31 .bashrc
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root    root   18 Dec  2 18:41 .ssh
```

I obviously get a "permission denied" when trying to access that directory.

```
sh-4.4$ ls /home/foobar/.ssh
ls: cannot open directory '/home/foobar/.ssh': Permission denied
```

I tried changing the ownership of the directory on the host to match the uid of the container user, but then it just looks like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 nobody  root   18 Dec  2 18:41 .ssh
```

My host user uid:gid is 501:100 and the container user is 1000:100.  Right now I'm just trying to generate an ssh key to upload to bitbucket, but this seems like a simple feature a container should be have.  All the tutorials and examples just stop after the --mount command instruction and say "there ya go!".  What good is the mount point if you can't read/write it?

EDIT:

I tried on Archlinux using docker instead of podman and it works like one would expect with both -v and --mount.  The owner of the mounted directory in the container matches the uid and gid of the host.  Is this then a bug in podman or is it just done differently?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a non-root user (foobar) in a rootless container. You must use `--userns=keep-id` for the container user to see the mounted volumes.

https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/rootless_tutorial.md#using-volumes

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because I have several containers running in a pod. Passing the --userns=keep-id flag into the podman run command gives the error "--userns and --pod cannot be set together". It seems it needs to be set at the pod level when teh pod is created, but this then messes up other containers by changing the user that they run their own processes as. Do you know if there is a better way?